# Getting rid of extra space with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, margin

I'm making a restaurant menu with tkinter in order to practice during the summer time. Below the name of the restaurant is a lot of blink space that I would like to get rid of in order to make my program look less scattered. This is the code I have currently.

```py
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1450x1050+0+0")
root.title("Flamin' Damon's")
root.configure(background='#000000')

Tops = Frame (root, width = 1450, height = 100, bd = 12, relief = "raise")
Tops.pack(side=TOP)
lblTitle = Label(Tops, font=('arial', 75, 'bold'), background='#e88215', text= "\tFlamin' Damon's\t\t\t")
lblTitle.grid(row =0, column=0)
BottomMainFrame = Frame (root,background='#000000', width = 1350, height = 650, bd = 12, relief = "raise")
BottomMainFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

F1 = Frame (BottomMainFrame, background='#e88215', width = 450, height = 650, bd = 12, relief = "raise")
F1.pack(side=LEFT)

F2 = Frame (BottomMainFrame,  background='#e88215', width = 450, height = 650, bd = 12, relief = "raise")
F2.pack(side=LEFT)
F2Top = Frame (F2,  background='#e88215', width = 450, height = 350, bd = 4, relief = "raise")
F2Top.pack(side=TOP)
F2Bottom = Frame (F2, width = 450, height = 300, background='#e88215', bd = 4, relief = "raise")
F2Bottom.pack(side=BOTTOM)

F3 = Frame (BottomMainFrame,background='#e88215', width = 450, height = 650, bd = 12, relief = "raise")
F3.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

I thought maybe adding (sticky = "NSEW") to the lblTitle.grid would fix the problem as I found a similar question on here but I got the same result. The white marking is the area I'm referring to. The area is the same in full screen and minimized.

```py
lblTitle.grid(row =0, column=0,sticky = "NSEW")
```

[image: Showing the area I wanna cut down]

Now I'm not tryna remove the area completely, but maybe 50% to 75% erased. Could it possibly be the dimensions of my root and frames? I've been playing around with them too. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you want the windows on the right to expand to fill the space? Or, do you want them to move up so all the space is at the bottom? Something else?

Comment: Is the top black(ish) rectangular area supposed to be a graphic of some sort, or is that what you're trying to remove?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I've circled in white marker the area I'm trying to shrink. I basically wanted to remove the empty space in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the blank space between `Tops` and `BottomMainFrame`, you need to have `BottomMainFrame` use and fill all additional space. You can do that with the `fill` (stick to all edges of the space allotted) and `expand` (consume any extra space not allotted).

```
BottomMainFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)
```

If you want the three vertical areas to use 1/3 of the horizontal space and all of the vertical space, you can use the same options there, too:

```
F1.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
F2.pack(side=LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
F3.pack(side=RIGHT, fill="both", expand=True)
```

You're doing a lot more work than you need to. It's generally advisable not to give sizes to frames. Instead, give sizes to the functional widgets and the whole UI will resize to fit. When you try to compute the size of each area, your program may not look the same on different machines due to font sizes, pixel density, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and examples! Much appreciated. I should've figured it'll look different on different machines because Google Docs and Microsoft Word have similar issues in how they handle sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Your root has height of 1050, the top frame has height 100 and the bottom 650. This leaves a height of 300 as the empty black space (maybe a bit less due to borders).

Easiest way to solve this would be to reduce the root height or to increase the height of either or the frames to leave a smaller gap - calculate it so that they will add up properly.

Another option will be to add a spacer frame, give it the height that's the difference you want to gap, and then pack it to the bottom before packing the ButtomFrame that way it will push the BottomFrame up.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I had to play with the root.geometry numbers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change root geometry to 850

or height of all bottom frames to 950